# cloud run request headers missing from flutter webview

Tags: flutter, webview, request, google-cloud-run, request-headers

I am trying to send a {Authorization : Bearer token} header with WebView to open our Flask website hosted on google cloud run. However, the header does not make it into Flask or google cloud is suppressing it. I have checked with https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending to verify that flutter WebView is sending the header.

When I use the header from a desktop browser, everything works.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Authorisation header is a reserved name that is chacked by GFE (Google Front End). You can't bypass it. So you have to change the header that your flutter app add, and read that custom header in your backend.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up putting the token in a cookie and that was able to get through google.

Comment: That's also a solution! The cookie is not as easy as header when it comes to the direct API call use case (with curl or service to service call).